# Angular-CLI create component in project library

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I have an Angular project with a library along with it. How do I create a component inside that library project?

Comment: How did you try to create it and what happened? Without e.g. a specific error message to search for this is going to be tricky for anyone with a similar problem to find.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By using --project flag. For a [reference](https://angular.io/cli/generate)

Example

```
ng g c component-name --project=project-name
```